# Easy util for formatting hard drive with GPT and grub2?

Tags: linux, hard-disk, bootloader

Is there a util to easily format an empty hard drive (or convert an existing set of partitions) so the drive afterwards has:

1. [*GPT* partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table), and...
2. is [grub2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) ready, and...
3. can still boot "legacy" OS partitions?

See ["example2" here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB#/media/File:GNU_GRUB_components.svg) for an illustration, specifically the red and orange portions.

I've partitioned a *GPT* & *grub2* disk before manually, using `gparted` and `gdisk` and whatnot, but it's the sort of job that seldom needs doing, so when it needs doing again 6 months later, I forget much of the method and wind up doing the steps in the wrong order.

What's wanted is not a partitioner as such, `gparted` already does a good job there... more something to get a hard drive ready for `gparted`.

Linux preferred, but whatever works best...